# ¿Cómo colocar varios selects en un form en React?

Tags: reactjs

Estoy haciendo un formulario dinámico para que se pueda enviar diferentes selects a través de un array. El formulario esta dentro de un componente el cual hace un map al array para construir los selects El problema que tengo es que cuando selecciono una opción se coloca en los demás selects que tengo

```
return (
<React.Fragment>
  {props.data.map((filter: IDropDownOpts) => (
    <ExpansionPanel
      className={classes.kshExpand}
      key={filter.id}
      variant="outlined"
      expanded={props.expandId[filter.id]}
      onChange={() => props.handleChange(filter.id)}
    >
      <ExpansionPanelSummary
        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
        id="panel1bh-header"
      >
        <p className={classes.kshTittle}>{filter.title}</p>
      </ExpansionPanelSummary>
      <ExpansionPanelDetails>
        <FormControl
          fullWidth
          id={`filters-${filter.id}`}
          variant="outlined"
        >
          <InputLabel htmlFor={`filters-${filter.id}`}>
            {filter.label}
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            id={`filters-${filter.id}`}
            name={`filters-${filter.id}`}
            fullWidth={true}
            labelId="mutiple-select-label"
            multiple
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={selected}
            renderValue={(selected: any) => selected.join(", ")}
          >
            {filter.options.map((option) => (
              <MenuItem key={option.key} value={option.value}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <Checkbox checked={selected.indexOf(option.value) > -1} />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={option.value} />
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        {selected.map((option: any) => (
          <Chip
            variant="default"
            size="small"
            label={option}
            color={"secondary"}
            onClick={() => handleClickChip(option)}
            style={{
              marginLeft: 5,
              marginRight: 5,
              borderRadius: 6,
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </ExpansionPanelDetails>
    </ExpansionPanel>
  ))}
</React.Fragment>
);
```

Esto me construye los oguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando selecciono una opción de cualquiera de los selects que se renderizan, todos los demas se llenan con el mismo valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrían ayudar viendo que estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente lo que está pasando es que TODOS los select están referenciando el mi `selected` y además todos están editando el mismo valor y de igual manera.

He hecho un sandbox que está funcionando: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-ardinghelli-cltcq?file=/src/Form.js

Vamos al código:

```js
   <Select
            id={`filters-${filter.id}`}
            name={`filters-${filter.id}`}
            fullWidth={true}
            labelId="mutiple-select-label"
            multiple
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={selected}
            renderValue={(selected: any) => selected.join(", ")}
          >
            {filter.options.map((option) => (
              <MenuItem key={option.key} value={option.value}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <Checkbox checked={selected.indexOf(option.value) > -1} />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={option.value} />
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
```

Si vemos el select:

- TODOS tienen `value={selected}`, entonces todos mostrarán el valor selected
- TODOS tienen `onChange={handleChange}`, entonces todos harán lo mismo al ser editados

A pesar, de que siempre queremos hacer lo mismo tenemos que buscar una manera de identificar el select y además una manera de almacenar distintos valores.

Entonces, hice un poco de código enfocado solo en el problema, posiblemente te ayude a corregir el tuyo si cambias el `onChange`, el `value`

```js
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (filterId, optionValue) => {
    const filter = props.data.find((filter) => filter.id === filterId);
    const option =
      filter.options &&
      filter.options.find((option) => option.value === optionValue);
    setAnswers({ ...answers, [filterId]: option });
  };
  return (
    <div className="Form">
      {props.data &&
        props.data.map((filter) => (
          <div key={filter.id}>
            <label>
              {filter.label}
              <select
                value={answers[filter.id] && answers[filter.id].value}
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(filter.id, e.target.value)}
              >
                <option value={""}></option>
                {filter.options.map((option) => (
                  <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                    {option.label}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
            </label>
            --- {answers[filter.id] && answers[filter.id].label}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Fijate en lo siguiente:

- Cree un valor `answers` que será donde guardareos TODAS nuestras respuestas (es un objeto)
- En la función `handleChange` recibo el `filterId` del select que estoy modificando y el `value`. Con estos valores busco la opción seleccionado y digo que mis respuestas serán igual a mis respuesta actuales, pero para el select será la opción seleccionada.
- En el select ahora el value es: `value={answers[filter.id].value}` es decir, la respuesta para ese filter en específico
- En el handle change invoco la función `handleChange`, pero pasando el id del select que está cambiando
- Finalmente, para el Chip tendría que seleccionar la respuesta para el filter.id PERO a diferencia de en el select que tenemos el `value`. Acá queremos mostrar el `label`.